# How to successfully run cudd library in window

Tags: binary-decision-diagram, cudd

is there any Binary Decision diagram (BDD) is available in windows.i tried to run cudd in vc++6.0..which is mention link
http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~alanmi/research/soft/softPorts.htm

but it isn't working properly.i get compiler error while running a sample code

Answer (score 0):

I compiled CUDD for Windows, but using MinGW not a Microsoft environment. My goal was that compiler since I use Dev-C as IDE.

I did a first try using Cygwin, but with no luck. The second try was with MSYS, an environment to run unix commands that come with MinGW for Windows. Note that CUDD uses a couple of POSIX libraries (such as ). Luckily they are used only in two secondary functions: CPU stats and a kind of fork that I didn't fully understood. Since I didn't need those, I simply commented the portion of code (in `util/cpu_stats.c`).

Then you only need to write a Makefile for MinGW in order to link the library! 
If you need it, I can send to you the library already compiled.